# Moved wordpress directs to old URL

Tags: wordpress

I just moved my wordpress site to a new sub domain. However the homepage still directs to the old url: wordpress.bysuonpera.com.
It should direct to photographer.bysuonpera.com

Anyone know where I can change this?

I already change the URL's in the wordpress settings menu. But this did not change the issue. Also, accessing wordpress through cpanel also directs to the old url.

Hope someone has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moving Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) is pretty straightforward. However there are some things that could be messed up, if you dont follow the guide. Ideally, you should change the URL setting in dashboard before transfer. However you can do it later on too, use [this section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_You_Have_Accidentally_Changed_your_WordPress_Site_URL) of the above manual.

As soon as you manage to login to dashboard on a new WP instance, download, activate and use two following plugins to replace old URL with new URL on your WP instance:
Velvet Blues Update URLs
Better Search Replace

Comment: It's not possible to simply change the url in a wp php file?

Comment: @suonpera you have to update `wp-login.php`, its all in the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_You_Have_Accidentally_Changed_your_WordPress_Site_URL) in my answer.

Comment: Didn't work. Do you know what the problem could be? If I try to access the wordpress site through cpanel, it tries to direct to the old url and then comes up with an 404 error.. file not found. Appreciate your help

Comment: @suonpera check your .htaccess file (it is in the same direcory with wp-login.php and wp-config.php). Do you see any old URLs there? If yes, then replace them with new ones.

Comment: @suonpera you can try this step from the manual:
If you forget to change the WordPress Address and Blog Address, you will be unable to change it using the wordpress interface. However, you can fix it if you have access to the database. Go to the database of your site and find the wp_options table. This table stores all the options that you can set in the interface. The WordPress Address and Blog Address are stored as siteurl and home (the option_name field). All you have to do is change the option_value field to the correct URL for the records with option_name=’siteurl‘ or option_name=’home‘.

Comment: I accessed the .htaccess file through filezilla, but there were no URLs. Am I supposed to access the wp-options table through the phpMyAdmin database in cpanel?

Comment: @suonpera Yes, proceed accessing wp-options table in the database for this wordpress instance.

Comment: @suonpera just select wp-options and on the right find the `option_name` and in this column then find `siteurl` and `home` and change the urls in these rows

Comment: Found them.. However both of them is the correct URL: http://photographer.bysuonpera.com.. So could the problem be fixed elsewhere? The upload_path is /home/suonpera/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads. Should I change it to /home/suonpera/public_html/photographer/wp-content/uploads?

Comment: @suonpera I am able to get to photographer.bysuonpera.com and as i go to photographer.bysuonpera.com/wp-admin i dont get redirected anymore. Can you login? Please explain more what exactly is the issue now? By the way, did you transfer the databases as was explained in the article in my answer above?

Comment: I just figured out I could change the url in cpanel -> web applications -> wordpress.. Solved the problem. Thanks for your help.. Really appreciate it!